# PHP syntax error, unexpected "?"

Tags: php, html

Here is my code, I understand that it is important to not mix html and php together on the same lines, but I can't get my head around this! Can anyone be of assistance? I have tried a few alternatives but I keep getting the syntax error unexpected '}'.

```
    <?php //Creating random number s
     $rid = rand(1,3); 
     echo $rid; if ($rid == 1){ ?>


     <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/result" method='post' id='quizForm' id='1'>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
    <ol>


    <li>
    <h3>What does PHP stand for?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='A' />
    <label for='answerOneA'>A) Hyper text markup language</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='B' />
    <label for='answerOneB'>B) PHP: Preprocessed hypertext</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerOne' id='answerOne' value='C' />
    <label for='answerOneC'>C) PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</label>
    </div>
    </li>


    <li>
    <h3>Who invented PHP?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='A' />
    <label for='answerTwoA'>A) Dick Dastardly </label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='B' />
    <label for='answerTwoB'>B) Rasmus Lerdof</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerTwo' id='answerTwo' value='C' />
    <label for='answerTwoC'>C) God</label>
    </div>
    </li>



     <li>
    <h3>What is PHP used for?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='A' />
    <label for='answerThreeA'>A) Creating dynamic webpages</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='B' />
    <label for='answerThreeB'>B) Server-side scripting</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answerThree' id='answerThree' value='C' />
    <label for='answerThreeC'>C) All of the above</label>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ol>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit Answers' />

    </form>
    <?php
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: You don't put another echo statement in a echo statement! Concatenate your strings!

Comment: This question has many answers already but you can decide to do `<?php

//Creating random number s
$rid = rand(1,3);
echo $rid;

 if ($rid == 1){
?>` Output all your HTML then open PHP again and close the open if statement `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Try `echo "<form action=\"".base_url()."\"";` and so on. Basically what Rizier said and this is how to do it/

Comment: sorry could you make that a little clearer for me please? I haven't slept for 2 days and my brain cannot function right now!

Comment: apologies again, tried your method out @OmniPotens and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @KGdB Great it helped you. You can mark my solution up so others seeking a near solution can look it up for assistance.

Comment: only one problem though, when i reopen the php tags for '}' after closing the form tag, it gives me an error saying unexpected '}'. it seems to be one error after the other with me :(

Comment: @OmniPotens any ideas on where it's going wrong?

Comment: You see, you called `echo` and after it you opened with `"YOUR HTML"` and inside of your form you have `<form action="`. The `"` opening in your form action has closed your PHP's `echo "` that you opened. Even if you used a `'YOUR HTML'` inside of your form you still have them so that nullifies the usage as well. It's the reason why my solution closes the PHP and allows you run all possible HTML then open again to close all open PHP tags. Hope you understand?

Comment: uh not entirely. I opened the php and closed it before the html, then after closing the html i reopened php to declare '}'. However the syntax error is saying this shouldn't be there?

Comment: @OmniPotens I have updated my code to show you what I mean.

Comment: now it's decided to change to unexpected end of file......

Comment: I believe my explanation has simplified the process. If you are still lost, create a chat room and invite me so I give your different instances on how to handle the scenario so you don't run into troubles next time as I see you are likely a beginner on the language.

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to join a chatroom let alone create a chat room :P